# What's the use of the logOnly option in ngrx DevTools?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I've read the minimalistic docs at https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/store-devtools, and understood that you can add instrumentation as follows:

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
  logOnly: environment.production
})
```

Supposedly, if the logOnly flag is true, your app will connect to the Redux DevTools extension in a log only mode, it'll have very little overhead as it shouldn't store the state data, but only log the action names that are happening during the runtime.

But in my experiments, I still see the state data in the ngrx DevTools panel, so what're the benefits of using `logOnly:true`?

Comment: What version of ngrx are you using? Looks like the `logOnly` flag was a recent addition for v5.0.0 on 1/22 (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store-devtools/CHANGELOG.md#500-2018-01-22)

Comment: I use ngrx 5.0.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://v9.ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/config#logonly):

> logOnly: boolean - connect to the Devtools Extension in log-only mode. Default is false which enables all extension features.

With a link to the [extensions features](https://v9.ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/config#features).

Based on this we can assume that setting `logOnly` to `true` will switch the following redux-devtools-extension features off:

```js
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
    features: {
        pause: true, // start/pause recording of dispatched actions
        lock: true, // lock/unlock dispatching actions and side effects    
        persist: true, // persist states on page reloading
        export: true, // export history of actions in a file
        import: 'custom', // import history of actions from a file
        jump: true, // jump back and forth (time travelling)
        skip: true, // skip (cancel) actions
        reorder: true, // drag and drop actions in the history list 
        dispatch: true, // dispatch custom actions or action creators
        test: true // generate tests for the selected actions
    }
})
```

This is ideal for production environments as you may not need or want these primarily dev-focused features running in your live application.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `logOnly` guarantee the integrity of the state**.

You can't modify it as e.g action dispatcher is switched off. In log-only mode, you can review the log, but you can't modify it.